# Displaying data from database not working properly in PHP/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, display

I have a survey form displaying questions, answertype and number of options from my question table. Here's my code.

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

$id = $_REQUEST['survey_id'];

$query =  "SELECT SF.survey_id, SF.surveytitle, SF.survey_description, SF.surveycategory, C.categoryname AS pcatname, SF.surveysubcategory, SC.categoryname AS scatname, SF.gender, SF.age_start, SF.age_end, SF.occupation, SF.date_created, O.name, SF.location, SF.occupation_status,  SF.status, SFQ.question_id, Q.questiontitle,L.location_name FROM surveyform AS SF
LEFT JOIN location AS L ON SF.location = L.location_id
LEFT JOIN category AS C ON SF.surveycategory = C.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS SC ON SF.surveysubcategory = SC.category_id
INNER JOIN occupation AS O ON SF.occupation = O.occupation_id
INNER JOIN surveyform_questions AS SFQ ON SF.survey_id = SFQ.survey_id
INNER JOIN question AS Q ON SFQ.question_id = Q.question_id WHERE SFQ.survey_id  = $id";






$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $surveyid = $row['survey_id'];
        $title = $row['surveytitle'] ;
        $category = $row['pcatname'] ;
        $subcategory = $row['scatname'] ;
        $gender = $row['gender'];
        $agestart = $row['age_start'];
        $ageend = $row['age_end'];
        $occupation = $row['name'];
        $location = $row['location_name'];
        $occupationstatus = $row['occupation_status'];
        $datecreated = $row['date_created'];
        $description = $row['survey_description'];

    }
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Preview Survey</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    h2.space {padding: 0%}
    h4.space {padding: 0%}

   </style>
   <?php error_reporting(0); ?>
  </head>
<body style="background-color:#f0f0f0;">
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">   
      <div class="panel-body">

<div class=col-md-6>
<a href="previewsurveys.php"><button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button></a>
<a href="AdminDashboard.php"><button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button></a></div>
<div style="float:right;"><h4><font color="grey"> Survey Code: <?php echo $surveyid ?></font></h4></div>

<br>
<hr/>

          <div class="col-md-6">

          <h2 class="space"><?php echo $title ?></h2><br>
          <h4>Description: <?php echo $description ?></h4>
          <font color="grey"> Created: <?php echo $datecreated ?></font>
          </div>
          <div style="float:right;">

          <div class="col-md-10">
          <table>
          <tr>
          <td>Gender: </td>
          <td><input type=text class=form-control value=" <?php echo $gender ?>" disabled><td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Age Range: </td>
          <td><input type=text class=form-control value=" <?php echo $agestart . " to " . $ageend . " y/o"; ?>" disabled></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Occupation: </td>
          <td><input type=text class=form-control value=" <?php echo $occupation ?>" disabled></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td>Location: </td>
          <td><input type=text class=form-control value=" <?php echo $location ?>" disabled></td>
          </tr>

          </table>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div style="padding: 40px;">

      <form name="Answers" method="POST">
      <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

$id = $_REQUEST['survey_id'];
$count=1;
$answer=0;
        $query =  "SELECT SF.survey_id, SF.surveytitle,  SF.surveycategory, C.categoryname, Q.answer_type, Q.Option_1, Q.Option_2, Q.Option_3, Q.Option_4, Q.Option_5, Q.Option_6, Q.Option_7, Q.Option_8, Q.Option_9, Q.Option_10 AS pcatname, SF.surveysubcategory, SC.categoryname AS scatname, SF.gender, SF.age_start, SF.age_end, SF.location, SF.occupation, O.name, SF.occupation_status, SF.status, SFQ.question_id, Q.questiontitle
         FROM surveyform AS SF 
         LEFT JOIN location AS L ON SF.location = L.location_id
        LEFT JOIN category AS C ON SF.surveycategory = C.category_id
        LEFT JOIN category AS SC ON SF.surveysubcategory = SC.category_id
        INNER JOIN occupation AS O ON SF.occupation = O.occupation_id
        INNER JOIN surveyform_questions AS SFQ ON SF.survey_id = SFQ.survey_id
        INNER JOIN question AS Q ON SFQ.question_id = Q.question_id
 WHERE SFQ.survey_id  = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $questions = $row['questiontitle'];
        $qid = $row['question_id'];
        $anstype = $row['answer_type'];


        echo "<b>Question ". $count.".)</b> ". $questions. "</br>";

        $count++;
        $answer++;

        ?>

                <?php
                $option1 = $row['Option_1'];
                $option2 = $row['Option_2'];
                $option3 = $row['Option_3'];
                $option4 = $row['Option_4'];
                $option5 = $row['Option_5'];
                $option6 = $row['Option_6'];
                $option7 = $row['Option_7'];
                $option8 = $row['Option_8'];
                $option9 = $row['Option_9'];
                $option10 = $row['Option_10'];

                ?>


                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $qid ?>" name="question_<?php echo $answer; ?>">

                <?php if(!is_null($option1)){ ?>
                    <div id="option1" style="display:none;">

                    <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option1;?>" id="<?php echo $option1 ?>"><?php echo $option1; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option1;?>" id="<?php echo $option1 ?>"><?php echo $option1; } ?> 

                    </div>

                    <br />
                <?php } ?>


                <?php if(!is_null($option2)){ ?>
                    <div id="option2" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option2;?>" id="<?php echo $option2 ?>"><?php echo $option2; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option2;?>" id="<?php echo $option2 ?>"><?php echo $option2; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>


                <?php if(!is_null($option3)){ ?>
                    <div id="option3" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option3;?>" id="<?php echo $option3 ?>"><?php echo $option3; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option3;?>" id="<?php echo $option3 ?>"><?php echo $option3; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option4)){ ?>
                    <div id="option4" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option4;?>" id="<?php echo $option4 ?>"><?php echo $option4; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option4;?>" id="<?php echo $option4 ?>"><?php echo $option4; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option5)){ ?>
                    <div id="option5" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option5;?>" id="<?php echo $option5 ?>"><?php echo $option1; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option5;?>" id="<?php echo $option5 ?>"><?php echo $option5; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option6)){ ?>
                    <div id="option6" style="display:none;">
                       <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option6;?>" id="<?php echo $option6 ?>"><?php echo $option6; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option6;?>" id="<?php echo $option6 ?>"><?php echo $option6; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option7)){ ?>
                    <div id="option7" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option7;?>" id="<?php echo $option7 ?>"><?php echo $option7; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option7;?>" id="<?php echo $option7 ?>"><?php echo $option7; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option8)){ ?>
                    <div id="option8" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option8;?>" id="<?php echo $option8 ?>"><?php echo $option8; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option8;?>" id="<?php echo $option8 ?>"><?php echo $option8; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option9)){ ?>
                    <div id="option9" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option9;?>" id="<?php echo $option9 ?>"><?php echo $option9; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option9;?>" id="<?php echo $option9 ?>"><?php echo $option9; } ?> 
                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!is_null($option10)){ ?>
                    <div id="option10" style="display:none;">
                        <?php if ($anstype == 'radiobutton'){ ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option10;?>" id="<?php echo $option10 ?>"><?php echo $option10; } ?>  

                        <?php if ($anstype == 'checkbox'){ ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option10;?>" id="<?php echo $option10 ?>"><?php echo $option10; } ?> 
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <br />
                <?php } }?>



                <hr>
               <input type="submit" name="submitsurvey"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
               <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" Name = "id"  VALUE = <?PHP echo $id; ?>>


            </form>





</div>
</div>
</body>
    </html>


<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submitsurvey'])) {


        for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
        $selected_radio = $_POST["answer_".$i];
        $idNumber = $_POST['id'];
        $questionid = $_POST["question_".$i];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];



        $database = "imetrics";

        $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","", $database );

        if($questionid <> "")
        {
            $qq = "INSERT INTO surveyperusername VALUES ('".$username."','".$idNumber."','".$questionid."','".$selected_radio."')";
            $rr = mysqli_query($con,$qq);
        }
        if ($con) {
            if($selected_radio == $option1) {
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_1 = Answer_1 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);      
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option2){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_2 = Answer_2 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option3){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_3 = Answer_3 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option4){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_4 = Answer_4 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option5){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_5 = Answer_5 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option6){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_6 = Answer_6 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option7){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_7 = Answer_7 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option8){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_8 = Answer_8 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option9){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_9 = Answer_9 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }
            else if($selected_radio == $option10){
                $query = "UPDATE results SET Answer_10 = Answer_10 + 1 WHERE survey_id = $idNumber AND question_id = $questionid";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            }


            else
            {

                   echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Survey Submitted!")';
        echo '</script>';
            }

        }
    }

}

 }

?>
```

This is the table where I'm getting the data to display

[image]

In this pictures it's only displaying 3 options for each question even though some questions have more than 3 options. How do I get it to display all the options that have value depending on each question and not just 3? Like some questions have more than 3 options that have value but it's only displaying 3[image]

[image]

When I remove style="display:none" 
[image]

when I remove the jquery code
[image]

what the top of my page looks like
[image]

Comment: show us your query?sql query  is missing..please update it

Comment: i guess the main problem is duplicate id . id attribute should be unique for each element .

Comment: You might not fetching all the fields in the query.

Comment: Edited. I put the query @Shanukk

Comment: From the screenshot the last record have 3 options have value and one more thing you are adding javascript outside the forloop that's why all the other options will get null value and because of that all the options are hidden. is it hidden because of duplicate ids

Comment: Edited again. the query was incomplete before.

Comment: What will be the alternate way? @PankajMakwana

Comment: what are the requirement of jquery below code?

Comment: I assumed that the maximum option there will be is 10. So the options are only from option1-option10 @PankajMakwana

Comment: is there any requirement of jquery code for hiding options?
if no then remove jquery code and remove style='display:none' on all options because condition itself decides to display or not

Comment: The options for each question dissapears when I remove the jquery code or the style='display:none' @PankajMakwana

Comment: Remove both jquery code and style='display:none'. because `if(!is_null($option2)){`, `if(!is_null($option3)){`, `if(!is_null($option4)){` and so on, if option is not set or value is null then option is not going to display. if condition is true then it will display. it's simple

Comment: Can you please edit your html so that I can get what you have done?

Comment: Done. I've put the whole code of my php file and also added another photo to show what's on top of my page @PankajMakwana

Comment: check below link and take code from it and replace with your code
https://pastebin.com/QpwDF1sD

Comment: Omg thank you so much it worked! @PankajMakwana do you have a messenger where can I chat you? if it's ok with you.

Comment: check my below answer @Jola

Comment: why your posting same question again and again @Jola

Comment: What do you mean? @JYoThI this is the first time i posted it

Comment: Then who posted this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671060/how-to-do-a-condition-displaying-input-type-based-on-table-column-in-php-javascr/44671315#44671309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `Id attribute` should be `unique` for each element.

2) You have much code `redundant` .reduce the code redundant using `for` loop .

3) Remove your unwanted `display:none` style property  and jquery . because you can able to handle the empty option in server side code .

**PHP :**  Simplified version of your code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $questions = $row['questiontitle'];
        $qid = $row['question_id'];
        $anstype = $row['answer_type'];
        $count++;
        $answer++;

        echo "<b>Question ". $count.".)</b> ". $questions. "</br>";


        $option1 = $row['Option_1'];
        $option2 = $row['Option_2'];
        $option3 = $row['Option_3'];
        $option4 = $row['Option_4'];
        $option5 = $row['Option_5'];
        $option6 = $row['Option_6'];
        $option7 = $row['Option_7'];
        $option8 = $row['Option_8'];
        $option9 = $row['Option_9'];
        $option10 = $row['Option_10'];

         ?>


         <input style="display:none" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $qid ?>" name="question_<?php echo $answer; ?>">

        <?php   
        for($j=1;j<=10;$j++)
        {

             if(isset(${'Option_'.$j}) && !empty(${'Option_'.$j}) )
             { 
             ?>

                   <div>
                        <input type="<?php if($anstype == 'radiobutton'){  echo 'radio'; }else{ echo 'checkbox';  }?>" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo ${'Option_'.$j};?>" id="<?php echo ${'Option_'.$j}; ?>"><?php echo ${'Option_'.$j};  ?>
                    </div>
             <?php  
             }
             ?>  


            <br/>

        <?php 
        } 
        ?>

                <?php  

    }

}  

?>
```